# How do i change activity layout using radio button? Android Studio

Tags: java, android

[Difficulty image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9r2L.png)

[Easy mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms7ox.png)

I'm developing a flag quiz game for android using android studio for my thesis.
How do I change the layout of my activity when I change the difficulty into normal and hard using radio button? can anyone give me example of coding?

```
private void popupWindow() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_difficulty, null);
    popupView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, popupView.getMeasuredWidth(), popupView.getMeasuredHeight(), true);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setIgnoreCheekPress();

    Button btnOk = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnok);
    Button btnCancel = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);

    mMode = (RadioGroup) popupView.findViewById(R.id.radioScreenMode);
    mMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (mMode.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                case R.id.radioeasy:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Easy Mode is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.radionormal:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Normal Mode is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.radiohard:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hard Mode is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                popupWindow.dismiss();


        }
    });
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: are you using multiple activities or single activity with multiple fragments or just use visibility. For the first option, you must use intents to switch. for second use fragment transaction. for visibility thing, just change the visibility of layout onclick.

Comment: i have multiple activities, and once i change the difficulty to hard it changes the layout. can you give me a example of code?

Comment: sorry for late response @angelo

Comment: you can use layout visibility i think on radio button selection or use Intent to call activity